# ERROR [5/5] COPY ./frontend && ./images ./a. > [5/5] COPY ./frontend && ./images ./app/: failed to compute cache key: "/&&" not found: not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build docker images for my React add and I am in a case that I need to copy the image folder which is located outside my react app( frontend) I have specified in my dockerfile to copy two folders from the destination to the source, but I am getting this error saying that `&&` is not found
NOTE: I can't ignore folder/files inside .dockerignore as I need to build the backend folder in the docker image as well? and also I don't want to have another COPY step like
`COPY ./frontend . COPY ./images .`
my docker file

```
FROM node:18-alpine
EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./frontend/package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY ./frontend && ./images .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: `COPY` is not a shell command, but a dockerfile directive. Hence we cannot use `&&`. I would suggest to either use two `COPY` instructions, or copy `.` with a corresponding `.dockerignore` in place.

Comment: You can also `COPY ./frontend ./images .`, but note that it will copy the contents of both directories into the image's `/app` directory losing a layer of directory hierarchy (there will not be an `/app/images` directory but just `/app/a0b1c.png` files with the contents).